# I am trying to return a table in stored procedure. This is what I have so far

Tags: oracle, procedure

My goal is to return a table using a stored procedure.

```
create or replace PACKAGE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS AS

    TYPE DETAILS IS RECORD(
      EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
      EMPLOYEE_LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
      EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(6,0) 
      );

    TYPE TABLE_EMPLOYEES IS TABLE OF DETAILS;

    PROCEDURE GET_EMPLOYEES(
    EMP_DEPT_ID EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE,
    EMP_SALARY employees.salary%TYPE,
    P_TBL_EMPLOYEES OUT L_TABLE_EMPLOYEES
    );

    FUNCTION IS_EMPLOYEE(EMP_ID EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE)
    RETURN BOOLEAN;

    END EMPLOYEE_DETAILS;
```

And this is the package body. I get error when I compile this. I haven't included the details for function `IS_EMPLOYEES` but it returns a boolean. I am a beginner to oracle programming. Can somebody please guide me to solve this problem?

```
 create or replace PACKAGE BODY EMPLOYEE_DETAILS AS

    PROCEDURE GET_EMPLOYEES(
    EMP_DEPT_ID EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE, 
    EMP_SALARY employees.salary%TYPE,
    P_TBL_EMPLOYEES OUT L_TABLE_EMPLOYEES
    )

    IS
    LC_SELECT SYS_REFCURSOR
    LR_DETAILS DETAILS;
    P_TBL_EMPLOYEES L_TABLE_EMPLOYEES;

    BEGIN
    OPEN LC_SELECT FOR 
    SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES
    WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=EMP_DEPT_ID
    AND
    EMPLOYEES.SALARY>EMP_SALARY;

    LOOP 
    FETCH LC_SELECT INTO LR_DETAILS;
    EXIT WHEN LC_SELECT%NOTFOUND;

    IF IS_EMPLOYEE(LR_DETAILS.EMPLOYEE_ID) THEN
    INSERT INTO P_TBL_EMPLOYEES VALUES(LR_DETAILS.EMPLOYEE_ID,LR_DETAILS.EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME,DETAILS.EMPLOYEE_LAST_NAME);

    END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE LC_SELECT;

    END GET_EMPLOYEES;
    END EMPLOYEE_DETAILS;
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: It says the table or view does not exist.

Comment: Give us the complete error including the line number!

Comment: In declaration (inside a procedure in package body) you have TBL_EMPLOYYEE, in code - TBL_EMPLOYEES.

Comment: @kevinnsky the error is:

Comment: Error(3,5): PLS-00410: duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not permitted

Comment: @Dmitry, i corrected that but I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incomplete logic is a bit perplexing: given that you are selecting from the EMPLOYEES table how can IS_EMPLOYEE() return anything but `true`?

Anyway, your actual problem is that INSERT is reserved for populating heap (permanent) tables.  `TBL_EMPLOYEES` is a collection, an in-memory structure and so needs to be treated like any other variable.

The simplest way of populating collections is with the SELECT ... BULK COLLECT INTO syntax.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/selectinto_statement.htm#sthref2355).  However , I will offer a solution which fits your logic:

```
PROCEDURE GET_EMPLOYEES(
    EMP_DEPT_ID EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE, 
    EMP_SALARY employees.salary%TYPE,
    TBL_EMPLOYEES OUT TABLE_EMPLOYEES
)

IS
    LC_SELECT SYS_REFCURSOR
    LR_DETAILS DETAILS;
    TBL_EMPLOYEE TABLE_EMPLOYEES;

BEGIN
    OPEN LC_SELECT FOR 
        SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME 
        FROM EMPLOYEES
        WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=EMP_DEPT_ID
        AND EMPLOYEES.SALARY>EMP_SALARY;

    LOOP 
        FETCH LC_SELECT INTO LR_DETAILS;
        EXIT WHEN LC_SELECT%NOTFOUND;

        IF IS_EMPLOYEE(LR_DETAILS.EMPLOYEE_ID) THEN
            TBL_EMPLOYEE.extend();
            TBL_EMPLOYEE(TBL_EMPLOYEE.count()) := LR_DETAILS;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE LC_SELECT;
    TBL_EMPLOYEES := TBL_EMPLOYEE;

END GET_EMPLOYEES;
```

By the way, you should make a effort to clearly distinguish the names of local variables and parameters: `TBL_EMPLOYEES` and `TBL_EMPLOYEE` are just too similar.  `P_TBL_EMPLOYEES` and `L_TBL_EMPLOYEE` are simple and obvious, and adopting such a naming convention will make debugging your code immeasurably easier.

Comment: thank you for your help. I have edited the code according to your suggestion. When I compile it it says:Error(31,5): PLS-00321: expression 'TABLE_EMPLOYEES' is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement

Comment: @ APC I am having problem is calling the function IS_EMPLOYEE and saving the passed results in a table and return. When I run your provided code, it gives error saying:PLS-00321: expression 'TABLE_EMPLOYEES' is inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement

Comment: Clearly you have mis-copied my solution, as I didn't mention `TABLE_EMPLOYEES` at all. Which I didn't do because it is *type declaration* and not a variable.  I refer you do my advice about the value of distinctive naming as an aid in debugging code (and avoiding errors in teh first place).

Comment: @ APC okay thank you. Can you please also tell me how can I execute this procedure and check the results? I really appreciate your help.